# how can i make a button on click move a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a div that I only want to be seen when a button is pressed to I positioned the div with a margin of `-600` then when the button is pressed, it moves the div to `margin: 0`.

Here is the HTML for the div and button:

```
<div id="mobile">
    <hr id="line">
    <ul id="listMobile">
        <li class="smallList"><span style="color:#ffe700">Home</span>
        </li>
        <li class="smallList">
            Gallery
        </li>
        <li class="smallList">
            Order Form
        </li>
        <li class="smallList">
            The Arena
        </li>
        <li class="smallList">
            Contact Us
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<button id="slideButton" onClick="toggleMenu();">
    <hr class="slider">
    <hr class="slider">
    <hr class="slider">
</button>
```

Here is the JavaScript (I'm still a beginner with JavaScript so go easy on me):

```
function toggleMenu () {
    if (document.getElementById("mobile").style.left == "0px") {
        document.getElementById("mobile").style.left = "-630px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mobile").style.left = "0px";
    }
}
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#mobile {
  margin:           0;
  margin-top:       0px;
  width:            250px;
  height:           1000px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-left:      -600px;
  position:         absolute;
  z-index:          -5;
}

.slider {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  height:           3px;
  width:            45px;
  margin-top:       10px;
  border-radius:    15px;
}

#slideButton {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border:           0;
  margin-top:       12px;
  margin-left:      15px;
  padding-right:    7px;
  padding-top:      7px;
  position:         fixed;
  border-radius:    5px;
  padding-left:     18px;
  visibility:       hidden;
}

#slideButton:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#slideButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.1);
  transition:       ease 0.6s;
}

#listMobile {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.smallList {
  display:        block;
  padding-top:    15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left:   0px;
  font-size:      45px;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is not working? Thanks!

Comment: what do u see in console?

Comment: im using a website called codepen, it has no console unfortunately

Comment: @Musty Codepen has a console just like any other site. Press F12.

Comment: Lol i cant even press f12. im using a chromebook and it doesnt have function keys. even if i try to turn function keys on, i only have 10 -_-

Comment: @Musty CTRL+SHIFT+J :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `margin-left` to move the element off screen, then altering `left` in your JS. You need to use one or the other.

```js
function toggleMenu(){

  if(document.getElementById("mobile").style.left == "0px")
 {document.getElementById("mobile").style.left ="-630px"

}
 else{
 document.getElementById("mobile").style.left = "0px"
}
}
```

```css
#mobile {
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #333333;
 left: -600px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -5;
 transition: left .5s;
}

.slider {
   border: none;
   background-color: white;
   height: 3px;
   width: 45px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   border-radius:15px;
}

#slideButton {
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

#slideButton:focus {
   outline: none;
}

#slideButton:hover {
   background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.1);
   transition: ease 0.6s;
}

#listMobile {
   margin-top: 100px;
}

.smallList {
   display: block;
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile">
  <hr id="line">
  <ul id="listMobile">
        <li class="smallList"><span style="color:#ffe700">
           Home</span>
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           Gallery
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           Order Form
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           The Arena
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           Contact Us
        </li> 
  </ul>   

    </div>

      <button id="slideButton" onClick="toggleMenu()">
          asdf
       </button>
```

Or you can continue to use `margin-left` to hide the menu, then use `left` to show it, but you need to use a positive value for `left`, not a negative one, and set the initial state of the menu to `left: 0px` for your conditional to work on the first click.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  if (document.getElementById("mobile").style.left == "0px") {
    document.getElementById("mobile").style.left = "630px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mobile").style.left = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#mobile {
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #333333;
 margin-left: -600px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -5;
 transition: left .5s;
}

.slider {
   border: none;
   background-color: white;
   height: 3px;
   width: 45px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   border-radius:15px;
}

#slideButton {
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

#slideButton:focus {
   outline: none;
}

#slideButton:hover {
   background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.1);
   transition: ease 0.6s;
}

#listMobile {
   margin-top: 100px;
}

.smallList {
   display: block;
   padding-top: 15px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile" style="left:0px">
  <hr id="line">
  <ul id="listMobile">
        <li class="smallList"><span style="color:#ffe700">
           Home</span>
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList"> 
           Gallery
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           Order Form
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           The Arena
        </li> 
     <li class="smallList">
           Contact Us
        </li> 
  </ul>   

    </div>

      <button id="slideButton" onClick="toggleMenu()">
          asdf
       </button>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, this worked. is there a way i could make it slowly slide in instead of instantly appearing?

Comment: @Musty ah it's all good, thanks. You just need to apply `transition` to whatever property you're changing. Updated my answer. Though technically the best thing to use with `transition` or `animation` is to change a `transform` and in this case, you would want to transition `transform: translateX()`. So I would use that instead, and refactor your code a little https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/pwjyzN

Answer (score 2):

Use `marginLeft` instead of `left` in your script:

```js
function toggleMenu() {

  if (document.getElementById("mobile").style.marginLeft == "0px") {
    document.getElementById("mobile").style.marginLeft = "-630px"

  } else {
    document.getElementById("mobile").style.marginLeft = "0px"
  }
}
```

```css
#mobile {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-left: -600px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
}

.slider {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#slideButton {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}

#slideButton:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#slideButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  transition: ease 0.6s;
}

#listMobile {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.smallList {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile">
  <hr id="line">
  <ul id="listMobile">
    <li class="smallList"><span style="color:#ffe700">
           Home</span>
    </li>
    <li class="smallList">
      Gallery
    </li>
    <li class="smallList">
      Order Form
    </li>
    <li class="smallList">
      The Arena
    </li>
    <li class="smallList">
      Contact Us
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<button id="slideButton" onClick="toggleMenu()">
          <hr class="slider">
          <hr class="slider">
          <hr class="slider">
       </button>
```